# Duda con la estructura interna de sockaddr_in

Tags: c, socket

Hola estoy estudiando sockets en C y me encontré con una duda respecto a esta estructura:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
   short int            sin_family;
   unsigned short int   sin_port;
   struct in_addr       sin_addr;
   unsigned char        sin_zero[8];
};
```

Al utilizar la función `connect`:

```
int connect(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *serv_addr, int addrlen);
```

Se supone que el segundo argumento es un puntero a `struct sockaddr` que es otra estructura distinta de `sockaddr_in`:

```
struct sockaddr {
   unsigned short   sa_family;
   char             sa_data[14];
};
```

Sin embargo eh visto como se pasa como argumento un `sockaddr_in` utilizando un casteo:

```
connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))
```

(`serv_addr` es un `struct sockaddr_in`)

Eh tratado de buscar respuestas en SO en ingles y eh podido entender que `sockaddr_in` tiene como primer elemento un `sockaddr` y por definición el puntero a una estructura es su primer elemento eso resolvería el problema si no fuese que en la definición de la estructura el primero elemento es un `short int sin_family;` como mostré en un comienzo.

¿Alguien podría explicarme esto?

fuentes:

[Unix Socket Client Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_client_example.htm)

[Pregunta de SO en ingles respecto a este tema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609397/whats-the-difference-between-sockaddr-sockaddr-in-and-sockaddr-in6)

Comment: En SO: https://www.google.es/search?q=common+initial+subsequence+struct+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @ninjalj precisamente uno de los objetivos de SOes es no ser dependientes de SOen. En casos como estos te invito a traducir la respuesta y publicarla en español. Así toda la comunidad hispana se podrá beneficiar de ello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo realmente la pregunta.

Al pasar un dato cualquiera como puntero, **no estás obligado a usar todo el dato**; por ejemplo

```
int arr[100] = { ... };

void algo( int *v ) {
  printf( "%d\n", *v );
}

algo( arr );
```

Ahí, pasamos un puntero a un bloque de 100 enteros, pero solo utilizas uno, el primero.

Con esto quiero decir que la función puede recibir cualquier cosa, pero tan solo ella (la función) sabe realmente lo que va a usar. Es responsabilidad nuestra, no obstante, el pasarle datos **compatibles** con lo que la función espera.

En versiones de C anteriores al C99, era muy habitual **ocultar** los datos reales con los que se trabajaba, creando un `typedef` en el archivo de cabecera, y luego realizar un `cast` explícito dentro del cuerpo de las funciones:

```
prueba.h

typedef void *handle;

void algo( handle data );
```

y, en el archivo de *implementación*:

```
prueba.c

#include "prueba.h"

struct RealData {
  int a;
  float b;
};

void algo( handle *h ) {
  struct RealData *rd = (struct RealData *)h;
  ...
}
```

Esto se haca para evitar que el *usuario* de nuestro código pueda *trastear* con los datos mas sensibles; un tipo de *ofuscación*; un intento de *limitar* la visibilidad de los datos.

Es posible ampliar esta técnica, aplicándola a `struct`. Con esta ampliación, se consigue el poder crear datos en la pila, sin necesidad de utilizar memoria dinámica (que es el caso del `typedef void *`):

prueba.h

```
struct Data {
  char zero[sizeof(int) * 2];
};

void algo( struct Data * );
```

prueba.c

```
#include "prueba.h"

struct RealData {
  int a,b;
};

void algo( struct Data *d ) {
  struct RealData *rd = (struct RealData *)d;
  ...
```

main.c

```
#include "prueba.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  struct Data d;

  algo( &d );
  ...
```

En este ejemplo, el usuario, realmente, está trabajando con `struct RealData`, pero **sin saberlo**, y **sin poder acceder a los campos** de la estructura.

Como último ejemplo, una técnica mas *avanzada* de conseguir lo mismo. Ahora, vamos a jugar con el enlazador. Es necesario duplicar mucho código aquí, puesto que desde la implementación **no se puede** incluir el archivo de cabecera.

prueba.h

```
struct Data {
  char zero[sizeof( int ) * 2];
};

void algo( struct Data );
```

prueba.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

// NO INCLUIMOS EL 'prueba.h' !!

struct Data {
  int a, b;
};

void algo( struct Data d ) {
  printf( "%d, %d\n", d.a, d.b );
}
```

main.c

```
#include "algo.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  struct Data d;

  algo( d );
  ...
```

Como se observa, con esta última técnica se pueden pasar datos **por valor**, **manteniendo la** *ofuscación* **de los mismos**.

En estas técnicas, lo único importante es que el tamaño de los datos *ofuscados* (`struct Data`) sea **igual o mayor** que el tamaño de los datos reales (`struct RealData`).

Es mas; como se indicó al inicio de la respuesta, ni siquiera eso es necesario. Lo único **realmente importante** es que los datos reales se encuentren donde los espera la función; si el código de nuestra función `algo` solo usa el campo `RealData.a`, podríamos pasarle un `int`, que la función no se enteraría. E, incluso, podríamos pasarle un `float`, que la función seguiría haciendo su trabajo. Los resultados serán *curiosos*, pero a la función le daría igual.

Bueno, después del *rollo* que he soltado, volvemos a la pregunta. Puedes considerar `struct sockaddr` como una versión *ofuscada* de `struct sockaddr_in`. Como se ha visto, ni siquiera es necesario que sean del mismo tamaño.

¿ El porqué de ambas estructuras ? Seguramente, por razones históricas; en algún momento, para ciertas funciones, se hizo necesario usar el *código sin ofuscar*; con el tiempo, y debido a sus ventajas, **ambas** estructuras se usaron indistintamente.